# PHP runs on root user not www-data

Tags: linux

I have multiple websites in a directory. One works fine as it runs on `www-data`. However the other site, which is on other folder runs on `root` user. I confirmed it by running  `get_current_user();` in php. How do I make `www-data` run it instead?